# Difficulty understanding a proposition in Fulton and Harris regarding $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, symplectic-linear-algebra

In Fulton & Harris, Proposition 23.1 (computing the fundamental groups of classical complex Lie groups) and the Exercises after it, specifically in dealing with $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$,

the book seems to suggest that the following two submanifolds are diffeomorphic to each other:
$$
M = \left\{ ((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}\times\mathbb{C}^{2n}
: x_1^Ty_2 - x_2^Ty_1 = 1 \right\} ,
\\
M' = \left\{ ((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}\times\mathbb{C}^{2n}
: x_1^Tx_1 + x_2^Tx_2 + y_1^Ty_1 + y_2^Ty_2 = 1 \right\} .
$$
In the book these are written as
$$
M = \{ (v,w) \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}\times \mathbb{C}^{2n} : Q(v,w) = 1\},
\\
M' = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^{4n} : z^T z = 1\} ,
$$
where $Q$ is an alternating non-degenerate quadratic form on $\mathbb{C}^{2n} \times \mathbb{C}^{2n}$, which I've put in "standard form" by picking a symplectic basis.

---

My guess is, $M$ and $M'$ are shown diffeomorphic by showing there is a change-of-basis on $\mathbb{C}^{4n}$ which takes the
$M$ expression to the $M'$ one.

However, I'm not sure how to find such a change-of-basis; how do I complete the argument here that $M$ and $M'$ are diffeomorphic?

Perhaps I'm missing something? Any help would be much appreciated!

---

Edit: as Stephen has pointed out in the comments, $(v,w) \mapsto v^Tv + w^Tw$ is not at all a bilinear form (as I'd incorrectly written earlier).

Comment: The expression $v^T v +w^T w$ doesn't seem to be bilinear, but rather quadratic in each variable, so I don't think your proposed strategy can work in exactly the way it's written.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see that $(v,w) \mapsto v^Tv + w^Tw$ is not at all bilinear; thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this just, you say that $Q$ is a symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$, and use that there exists a basis (sometimes called (standard) symplectic basis) in which the symplectic form has the matrix representation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0_n&-1_n\\1_n&0_n\end{pmatrix}?
$$
So I don't see any problem with your argument.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the quadratic equations you wrote are (in various coordinates) the equations for vectors being "isotropic" for the symplectic form $Q$, that is, $Q(v)=0$. EDIT2: others are $\{v:Q(v)=c\}$ for some constant $c$.

It is a not-completely-trivial theorem that, up to isomorphism (change-of-basis) there is a unique non-degenerate alternating form on a vectorspace of a given (even) dimension. The relevant change-of-basis is linear over whatever groundfield (maybe we need characteristic not 2), $v\to Av$, so $v\to v^\top Qv$ becomes $v\to (Av)^\top Q(Av)$, which means that the matrix of the symplectic form transforms by $Q\to A^\top QA$.

EDIT: And, if we want $\{v:Q(v)=c\}$ for any constant $c$, Witt's theorem assures that the symplectic group is transitive on such vectors.

Answer (score 1):

So after some initial confusion, I've managed to work out the details of the argument.

We have
$$
M = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^{4n} : B(z,z) = 1\} 
$$
where $B : \mathbb{C}^{4n} \times \mathbb{C}^{4n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the *symmetric* non-degenerate complex bilinear form given w.r.t. the standard basis by the matrix
$$ W =
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
 &  &  & I\\ 
 &  & -I & \\ 
 & -I &  & \\ 
I &  &  & 
\end{bmatrix} \,.
$$
Now, because the matrix $W$ is real and symmetric (and nonsingular), in particular (by first applying the spectral theorem) it is possible to show $A^TWA = I$ for some change-of-basis matrix $A$.